# Polynomial ring in countably many indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $F[x, y_1, y_2, ... ]$ be the polynomial ring in the infinite set of variables $(x, y_1,y_2,....)$ over a field $F$, and let $I$ be the ideal $(x-y_1^2,y_1-y_2^2,...,y_i- y_{i+1}^2, . . . )$ in this ring.
Define $R$ to be the ring $F[x, y_1,y_2,... ]/ I$, so that in $R$ the square of each $y_{i+1}$ is $y_i$; and $y_1^2\equiv x\pmod I$, i.e., $x$ has a $2^i$th root, for every $i$. Denote the image of $y_i$ in $R$ as $x^\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Let $R_n$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $F$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$.

(a) Prove that ${R_1}\subseteq{R_2}\subseteq{R_3}\subseteq\cdots$ and that $R$ is the union of all $R_n$, i.e., $R =\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}R_n$.

(b) Prove that $R_n$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable over $F$, so that $R_n$ is
a PID. Deduce that $R$ is a Bezout Domain (cf. Exercise 7 in Section 8.2). [First show
that the ring $S_n = F[x, y_1 , ... , y_n ]/ (x - y_1^2, y_1 - y_2^2, . . . , y_{n-1} - y_n^2) $ is isomorphic
to the polynomial ring $F[y_n]$. Then show any polynomial relation $y_n$ satisfies in $R_n$
gives a corresponding relation in $S_N$ for some $N\geq n$.].

(c) Prove that the ideal generated by $ x,x^{1/2}, x^{1/4},  ...$ in $R$ is not finitely generated (so
$R$ is not a PID).

This is the problem number 12 from Dummit & Foote's Exercise 9.2. The (a) part and the (c) part are understandable to me. In the part (a) we can just show that the generators of $R_i$ are generated by the generators of $R_{i+1}$ and in (c) assuming the contrary we can claim $(x,x^{1/2}, x^{1/4}  ...)$ is a finitely generated ideal say, $D= (x^{i_1},x^{i_2}, x^{i_3},  ...,x^{i_k})$ and pick $m\lt \min({i_1},{i_1},...,{i_k})$ and claim $D$ can't generate $x^m$ where $m=\frac{1}{2^s}$ for some $s\in\Bbb{N}$.

But, I don't understand (b) at all. Showing the ring isomorphism is easy but I don't understand the situation after that. Like why there should be some polynomial relations, and if there should then what kind of polynomial relation ? How $R_n$ would look like and how there should be such $N$ and I feel very confused about the whole situation. I feel I have to show $R_n\cong S_N$. And the initial ring isomorphism prepares the ground for it. But that's it and I feel lost. Any elaborate explanation will be much appreciated.

P.S. This is my first post. So, my coding skill is not upto par. I hope I left nothing inconceivable.Thank you all.

Comment: For example, $y_n^2y_{n-1}-y_{n-2}=0$ is a polynomial relation that involves $y_n$ in $R_n$ and you want to show it is true in $S_N$ for all $N\geq n$.  The reason we need this is to show two elements are the same in $R_n$ iff they are the same in $S_n$, i.e., we won't actually need to invoke the relators $y_n-y_{n+1}^2,y_{n+1}-y_{n+2}^2,\dots$ in $R$, i.e., the obvious $S_n\to R_n$ has trivial kernel.

Comment: But your polynomial relation is on R not on $R_n$ and is identically 0 on $R_n$ and it is true for all $N\ge n$ not just for some $N\ge n$. And if all the possible relations is of such form then the author might as well have said $R_n\cong S_n$ in the hint. So, it still doesn't clear my doubt.

Comment: Well, I think we might be able to show that $R_n=F[\overline {y}_n]$. Since $R_n$ is the smallest subring of $R$ contains $F$ and $y_n$, it must be contained in $F[\overline {y}_n]$, and the other side of containment is obvious due to the ring operations. This also can be seen as the subring of the ring given by the hint.